# Send slack messages using webhooks to own URL

Tags: slack, slack-api

We are trying to integrate Slack with our salesforce application. Every day there will be new users added in our slack and the same user will be there in salesforce also.

Inorder to maintain some hisory and reporting purpose we are planning to send all the messages to salesforce in the one to one chat. From the documentation I am seeing messages posted in chennels can be retrived but is there a way we can retrive the direct message chat also.

I tried the API documentation but not able to get proper solution for it.